# What is better to use: "2".toString() === 2.toString() OR "2" == 2?

Tags: javascript

I don't know what is better to use:

```
var s = "2";
var i = 2;
if(s.toString() === i.toString()){
    //do something
}
//OR

if(s == i){
    //do something
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I would go with first approach because it does exactly what we want.

Comment: what's your objective first..?

Comment: I agree with @Mr_Green, the first approach is much clearer, javascript has some odd type coercing rules as well.

Comment: To be more specific, in my code i don't know what are s and i the types, so I need the best why to compare them, but I need that the result of "2" and 2 to be true. Thanks

Comment: `I need that the result of "2" and 2 to be true` than the second way, why would think about the first one if you do not care about types?

Comment: `2.toString()` won't work because of a bug in JS interpreter. It will think `2.` is a beginning of a fracture. You need to put a space o a 2nd dot there: `2 .toString()` or `2..toString()`

Comment: If you want to compare them both as numbers, use `if (Number(s) === Number(i))`, if you want to compare them both as strings, use `if (String(s) === String(i))`. Try to avoid automatic coercion (`==`), as that can be quite confusing sometimes.

Comment: @Cheery very true.. agreed.

Comment: What about `2` and `"02"`?

Comment: Not handling `2.toString` is not a "bug in the JS interpreter". It's expected behavior, a consequence of number parsing rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually comparing two separate things, in first, you are casting both the variable values to a string and comparing, and the other comparison is lose one i.e you are not actually checking the data types of those variables. so it will return true if you compare `string` with `int` with a same value.

According to me, what you should be using is `===` which will not only compare the values but their data types as well because the ones you are using are both considered lose.

If you do not consider at all about data type then using `==` will suffice. You don't have to cast the values to a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example if for any reason you get a 2 with a space, it will evaluate false (even with ==):

```
var s = " 2"; // 2 with a sneaky space
var i = 2;
if(s.toString() === i.toString()){ // will be false
    //do something
}
```

Personally I prefer using ===, but I would change the values to integers, instead of to strings.

```
var s = " 2"; // 2 with a sneaky space again
var i = 2;
if(Number(s) === Number(i)){ // will be true
    //do something
}
```

You don't need the second Number() but, I don't know, you may get data that is also a string.